# When I pull Tilt Chain, why don't my vertical blinds tilt?

Tags: blinds

Please see [this video WITH SOUND](https://gfycat.com/simpleunawarefinwhale). How upload SOUND video here?  Don't hesitate edit this post to add it for me. I was pulling on Tilt Chain, but vertical blinds don't tilt! Why?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this after watching a YouTube video. Nothing was broken. I think I just turned each vertical blind wrong way.  I  turned each vertical blind other way, and tilt chain works now!

Answer (score 1):

There is a rotating element (usually a splined tube) that runs down the middle of the track, through each carrier. The tilt chain is attached to the end of the splined-tube rotating element and when the tilt chain is pulled, the rotating element turns (longitudinally/axially) and turns a ring gear within each carrier. The ring gear in the carrier mates with a pinion gear that the stem attaches to, causing the stem to rotate when the chain is pulled (i.e. causes the vanes to tilt).

Because it is **very unlikely** that every single ring & pinion carrier gearset is damaged, it is **highly likely** that the tilt chain mechanism is broken where it attaches to and rotates the splined-tube rotating element.

Comment: P.S.- this usually means that you need to buy new blinds.

Comment: Rats! I don't want spend money when COVID19 un-employed me!!! But thanks for assistance. Can you pls add pictures to your answer? My English is primitive. I don't understand those terms like "splined tube", "carrier", "splined-tube rotating element", "ring gear", "pinion gear", "stem", etc...

Comment: @ElaineNai Adding images to define all of these things would be a nice bonus, however you can do the search and find some text and/or an image just as well as Jimmy could. As a bonus, if the first one doesn't make sense to you, you can continue searching until you find a description that works for you instead of asking Jimmy to do additional searches for you.

Comment: Have you contacted a blind repair company in your area? Sometimes these blinds can be repaired for less money than replacing it. They should be able to tell you over the phone what it would cost.

Comment: You are right but these are generally easy to fix and you can find generic pieces cheaply sometimes.   For something as trivial as this I would not trash the blinds.

Comment: @DMoore Pls elaborate? "these are generally easy to fix" what are "these"?